# How to find out the relation between liquid lens curvature and changing the focal point?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, curvature, lenses

I have a question regarding liquid lens.
how much we have to change the curvature to get an image shift of 30mm?

Comment: Read https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/652435/working-of-liquid-lens